Declaring variables in loop versus before loop
Test #1
I have the SQL below that iterates through a cursor which has 374 records. I've tested the
query a dozen times and it runs in 3 mins 40 secs (give or take a few seconds).
Test #2
I modify the query so that all declare statements appear before the while loop, the query then consistently completes 15 - 20 seconds faster.
I would have thought there would be almost no noticeable difference. Is a declare statement within a loop that much overhead, or is something else at play?
The cursor deals with the exact same records in both tests. I run test 1, then 2, then 1 again, then 2 again, etc. Test 2 has not run any worse than 8 seconds faster than test 1.
I'm pretty sure the declare statements are not causing the issue, but I can't explain why test 2 is consistently faster.
I should also mention that there are no other connections to the database while the tests are running.
declare @fillfactor int = 100


declare tableCursor CURSOR for
select  table_catalog, table_schema, table_name
from    information_schema.tables
where   table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
order   by table_schema, table_name

open tableCursor

declare @db varchar(128), @schema varchar(128), @table varchar(128)

fetch next from tableCursor into @db, @schema, @table

declare @cmd nvarchar(2000)
declare @lastLogged datetime = getdate()
declare @msg as varchar(500)
declare @startDate datetime = getdate()
declare @processed int = 0

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    declare @tableQualified varchar(200) = concat('[', @db, '].[', @schema, '].[', @table, ']')

    set @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @tableQualified + ' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100)'
    exec (@cmd)

    fetch next from tableCursor into @db, @schema, @table

    set @processed += 1

    declare @now datetime = getdate()

    if datediff(second, @lastLogged, @now) > 30
    begin
        declare @elapsedSec int = datediff(second, @startDate, @now)
        declare @mins int = @elapsedSec / 60
        declare @seconds int = @elapsedSec % 60

        set @msg = concat(@processed, ' tables processed in ', @mins, 'm ', @seconds, 's')
        raiserror (@msg, 10, 1) with nowait
        
        set @lastLogged = getdate()
    end
END


Instead of trying to roll your own I'd strongly advise using Ola Halengren's Index maintenance scripts. For example, EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @FragmentationLow = NULL, @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE', @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE', @FragmentationLevel1 = 5, @FragmentationLevel2 = 30, @LogToTable = 'Y' will rebuild or reorg all tables based on the fragmentation level and log results

In any case you only posted a single incomplete script (where's the cursor?). We can't say why one script or the other behaves differently like this. The "fast" script may be skipping tables or the "slow" script may have an extra slow operation.

No idea why it's any other way, but watch out with declares in loops, they aren't re-initialized so the original values are being kept. This might not be a problem in your case, but it's something a lot of people miss out

Also you are not using QUOTENAME it should be declare @tableQualified nvarchar(1000) = CONCAT_WS(',', QUOTENAME(@db), QUOTENAME(@schema), QUOTENAME(@table))

@PanagiotisKanavos The two scripts are IDENTICAL except for where I declare the variables.

I do not believe it makes any difference, as long as the variable is lexically declared before it is referenced.. Even when declared inside the loop, the value persists across loop iterations.  See this fiddle.

Expanding on @siggemannen comment - Variables declared without an explicit initializer will not be reinitialized (reset to null) with each loop iteration.  However, if an explicit initializer is present, the initialization expression will be evaluated and result assigned to the variable with each iteration.

We can't guess what's going on from partial code. Besides, the indexes aren't in the same state every time. The variable declarations won't cause seconds-long delays. Differences in cursor execution would. We don't know how you measured performance either. DO use Ola Hallengren's scripts as a baseline, if only because they properly log results instead of using RAISERROR.

@PanagiotisKanavos RaiseError is only there to log messages immediately instead of the buffered print.

@PanagiotisKanavos I've posted the entire SQL. But since the only thing I'm changing is where I declare the variables, I can't see the cursor mattering (and people on here tend to complain when you post too much code).

Why not check the fragmentation prior to a full rebuild? One rule of thumb is if the fragmentation is greater than 30% then rebuild, else if the fragmentation is greater than 5% then reorganize.

@RossBush It's just a test script run on a dev's machine.
